# Adding annotation to not annotated type in a programmatically way

Tags: java, annotations

I'I'm testing a code written according to this article:

https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2016/05/27/changing-annotation-values-at-runtime/

and it works for a case when class has at least one annotation at the class level. In case of scenario when I'm adding annotetion to class which is not annotated at all I got `UnsupportedOperationException` due to the fact that:

```
Object annotationData = method.invoke(clazzToLookFor);
```

return `Class:AnnotationData` with a field '`annotation`' which is an `emptyMap`. (if tha class is already annotated by at least one annotation it is a `LinkedHashMap`)

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: If you're using reflection to access that field anyway, might as well reassign it with a new map that's not empty

Comment: To do it by reflection you need to use illegal access to the field which will be denied in a future release (Java 18+)